# django updating multiple instances with different foreignkey

Tags: django, duplicates, foreign-keys

I'm trying to duplicate multiple data I only need to change their related foreignkeymy problem is that I'm able to duplicate but with the same foreignkey below is my code
any suggestions please

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Client(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    married = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname + " " + self.lname + " " + str(self.cat)


def show_category(request, cat_id):
    clients = Client.objects.filter(cat__id=cat_id)
    if request.method =='POST':
        for i in clients:
            i.id = None
            i.cat.id=3
            i.save()
        return redirect('/')


    context = {'clients':clients}
    return render(request, 'app/home_cat.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation on [copying model instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances):

```py
    def change_category(clients, new_category_id):
        for client in clients:
            client.pk = None
            client._state.adding = True
            client.cat_id = new_category_id
            client.save()
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I am receiving the following error: Cannot assign "4": "Client.cat" must be a "Category" instance.

Comment: @FadyGhalayiny yep that should be `client.cat_id = new_category_id`